# Can I sell unwanted items to earn credits?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've found some guns and modifications laying around that I don't plan to use.  Is there a way to sell them and put the credits toward things that I am going to use?  Or are they just worthless to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not sell things. They are worthless to you.

Answer (score 0):

no you cannot sell things back once you buy it you have to keep it FOREVER